# Passing down extra arguments via ArgumentParser

Tags: python, argparse

So I have a script in which my argument parsing functions are separated for a cleaner design. Ultimately, I wish to run a single command and have all the arguments parsed by those 3 functions. The command would look like:

`python3 rhize_refactored.py -l <str>, -sa, [-cr], -si <int>, -i <input_path>, -o <output_path>, [-r], [-c]`

In order for all arguments to be recognized, I've set up the script so that any extra arguments ignored by the first argument parsing function get passed on to the second argument parsing function, and again with the third argument parsing function. That part looks like this:

```
#Argument parsing functions#
def parse_args_language():
   parser=ArgumentParser(prog= 'rhize.py')
   parser.add_argument('-l', dest='language', choices= ['bash', 'python'], type=str, default='bash') #required

   args, extras1= parser.parse_known_args() #pass extras down to parse_args_bash()
   return args
   return extras1

def parse_args_bash(extras1):
   parser=ArgumentParser()
   parser=parser.add_argument('-sa', action='store_true') #required
   parser=parser.add_argument('-cr', action='store_true') #optional
   parser=parser.add_argument('-si', type=int) #required
   parser=parser.add_argument('-i') #required
   parser=parser.add_argument('-o') #required

   args=parser.parse_args(argv =extras1)
   extras2= parser.parse_known_args() #pass extras down to parse_args_repo
   return args
   return extras2

def parse_args_repo(extras2):
   parser= ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('-r', action= 'store_true') #optional
   parser.add_argument('-c', action= 'store_true') #optional

   args=parser.parser_args(argv=extras2)
   return args

   ##############################################################

def rhize_bash():
   args, extras1= parse_args_language()
   parse_args_bash(extras1)
   make_templates() 
   ....

def make_templates():
   args, extras2= parse_args_bash()
   parse_args_repo(extras2)
   ...

def main():
   language= parse_args_language()
   if language == "bash":
       rhize_bash()
   if language == "python":
       rhize_python() #omitted from this post

   print("Completed the run.")
main()
```

Have I set this up the right way? Because when I try running the full script, it appears to run through it fully, even though I know it shouldn't.

Comment: You left off the code that calls these 3 functions, though I can guess what it does.  By 'run through it fully' does that mean it ends up calling all 3?  That sounds perfectly normal, unless you check whether any of the `extras` lists is empty.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. The rest of the code is pretty lengthy and complicated so I didn't want to post it all here. But yes, I have a print statement at the end of my main() section to see if it ran fully (including calling those 3 functions), and it prints it no matter how many arguments I include in my command line...which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: You don't have to give the full code, but the functions by themselves don't tell us anything about how they are called, or how you decide which ones to call or not.  Actually your functions are missing something important - the return statement (or args and extras).

Comment: @hpaulj: I've added the codes that call to the parsers, as well as the return statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to make the code flow correctly.  I haven't tested it.

```
#Argument parsing functions#
def parse_args_language():
   parser=ArgumentParser(prog= 'rhize.py')
   parser.add_argument('-l', dest='language', choices= ['bash', 'python'], default='bash')

   args, extras1 = parser.parse_known_args() #pass extras down to parse_args_bash()
   return args, extras1   # return a tuple of items


def parse_args_bash(extras1):
   parser=ArgumentParser()
   parser=parser.add_argument('--sa', action='store_true') 
   # store_true actions are always optional
   parser=parser.add_argument('--cr', action='store_true')
   parser=parser.add_argument('--si', type=int) 
   parser=parser.add_argument('-i') 
   parser=parser.add_argument('-o') 

   args, extras2= parser.parse_known_args() #pass extras down to parse_args_repo
   return args, extras2


def parse_args_repo(extras2):
   parser= ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('-r', action= 'store_true') 
   parser.add_argument('-c', action= 'store_true') 

   args=parser.parser_args(argv=extras2)
   return args

   ##############################################################

def rhize_bash(extras1):
   args1, extras2 = parse_args_bash(extras1)
   make_templates(extras2) 
   ....

def make_templates(extras2):
   args2 = parse_args_repo(extras2)
   ...

def main():
   args, extras1 = parse_args_language()
   if args.language == "bash":
       rhize_bash(extras1)
   elif args.language == "python":
       rhize_python(extras1) #omitted from this post

   print("Completed the run.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `parse_args_bash` and `parse_args_repo` return separate `args` namespace objects.  We could pass the `args` to `parse_args_repo`, and have it add its values to that.  But I'll skip that step for now.

Your code called `parse_args_language` a couple of times, once to get the `args.language` value, and once to get `extras1` to pass to on. No harm in doing that, but rewrote it so it is called just once.

Since it is using `parse_known_args`, `parse_args_bash` should work using the default `sys.argv`, since it would just ignore the `-l` argument.  But it's also ok to work with `extras` which strips that out.